# Ubuntu 18.04 crashes when laptop runs on battery

Tags: 18.04, power-management, hp, battery, crash

I'm having a problem with my HP laptop, and I'm not really sure if it is a OS problem, but rather a hardware one. First of all the laptop model is HP 15-db1100nm. Most of the time my laptop has been plugged in, I rarely use it only on battery power. But now I need to do some work only on battery power, and the OS keeps crashing when it is unplugged. But this isn't always the case, sometimes it works fine and sometimes not. When I say crash I mean the screen just goes black and I can't do anything, but to hold down the power button and shut it down. It usually happens when there is some load, most of the time web browsers make that happen. To be more precise the only programs which led to this behavior are Chrome, Firefox and TeamViewer, but I kinda think that other programs might aswell do the same thing. Sometimes it works just fine even when these programs are running.
So what I've done so far is that I checked my battery status with
`upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1`
and the result was:

```
  vendor:               Hewlett-Packard
  model:                PABAS0241231
  serial:               41167
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sri 01 Dec 2021 16:03:51 (8 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              40,7094 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         40,7094 Wh
    energy-full-design:  41,04 Wh
    energy-rate:         1,539 W
    voltage:             12,923 V
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            99,0278%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
```

Because I thought it might be a OS problem, I was running XUbuntu 18.04, I did a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 (I'm not going for the 20.04 LTS version because I can't get the WI-FI adapter to work).
About a year ago I was using Windows 10 on the same laptop, and it kept crashing for some strange reasons no matter if it was plugged in or not. Xubuntu was crashing when plugged in aswell but only when it tried to go to sleep etc. When I disabled those options it stopped.
A few months ago I've added one more 8GB RAM module and that's all the hardware modifications I've done. If it matters it is a 3200MHz module, but runs on 2400MHz as it is the limit.
I tried to check CPU temperature, but couldn't detect any sensors with `sudo sensors-detect`.
I suspect it is a hardware problem but am really not sure. I'd appreciate any help. I'll probably go to some technician, but currently I have no time and I really need my laptop.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update UEFI before any further troubleshooting.

Comment: There *may* be some useful information in `/var/log/syslog` to explain the reason for the issue 

Comment: So today I tried to boot only on battery and it didn't work. I tried it twice but it couldn't load. The Ubuntu loading screen shows, than gets stuck and after that only black screen. I'll paste the syslog in the Answers section. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it safe to paste the output, does it contain any vulnerable information. And also is there anything particular that I should look for.